# find command with negated condition still considers the given directory

Tags: find

Wanting to find for files except for those, that are in /home directory (directly or in one of subdirectories of any level), I run the following command:

```
find / ! -path '/home/*'
```

However, I get error messages with "Permission Denied" message, like the following:

```
find: '/home/user/here/is/some/file': Permission denied
```

I don't care that it is "permission denied" per se, what I don't like is that it even tries to search there.

At first I thought that could be because there is some symbolic link from other places on FS, that references a directory inside /home/user/, but then I tried with -H option like this:

```
find -H / ! -path '/home/*'
```

and it still listed those files/directories inside /home/*.

Any ideas, how to rectify that?

Answer (score 2):

The `-path` component is evaluated for every possible path. It doesn't short-circuit the search - you need `-prune` for that

```
find / -path '/home/*' -prune -o -print
```

Comment: In particular, it doesn't interpret the contents of the pattern to determine that it will match everything under `/home`. Here, it would be relatively simple to do, but the pattern could be something like `/home/*x`, which requires looking at every file, and there could be a more complex set of conditions (and actions) than just a single `-path`.